# percona mysql crashing at innodb initialization

Tags: mysql, recovery, percona

i have a slave percona db setup that also maintains few of it's own tables

it started crashing with this in error.log:

```
InnoDB: In a MySQL replication slave the last master binlog file
InnoDB: position 0 4047010, file name bin-log.000529
InnoDB: and relay log file
InnoDB: position 0 4047154, file name /var/mysql/relay/relay-log.001563
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 71871595, file name /var/mysql/bin/bin-log.001518
120709  9:00:27  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120709  9:00:27 - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=2147483648
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2427524 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = (nil) thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x39)[0x8024a9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_segfault+0x3c2)[0x519df2]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xef60)[0x7f3edfb98f60]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x838d8f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x935e67]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x936795]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x92c2bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8579f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x84ce2c]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x68ba)[0x7f3edfb908ba]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f3edee3202d]
```

after that mysql process dies

there is enough memory on server - that is not the cause

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

solved by upgrading server from 5.5.13 to 5.5.20